Why does $[T \circ S]_B = [T]_B \circ [S]_B$ in linear algebra?
Why does $[T \circ S]_B = [T]_B  [S]_B$ in linear algebra?
why are they equivalent to apply the transformation first and then change the basis to a matrix, or change the basis to a matrix first and then apply the transformation? why are they equivalent?
$[T \circ S]_B = [T]_B \circ [S]_B$?
I know $[T]_B$ is a matrix

The $\circ$ is function composition.

@fatFeather There is no general answer to the question of which is better. It is important to know that the two operations are equivalent. Sometimes you are given $[S]_B, [T]_B$ as descriptions of $S$ and $T$, in which case using the matrices is probably the way to go, and sometimes you have some description of the maps $S$ and $T$ that might give you another way to deal with $S \circ T$.

why are they equivalent

A short, informal answer: the matrices are the same because they do the same thing, and matrices that do the same thing are necessarily the same. For any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $[T\circ S]_B x$ and $[T]_B[S]_B x$ both correspond to applying the transformations $S$ and $T$ to some vector $v \in V$, so both products yield the same result.
A long, formal answer: here is an outline of a proof that $[T \circ S]_B = [T]_B [S]_B$. I assume that you are working with real numbers, but the proof is field-agnostic. The extent to which the bulleted steps below require a separate proof depends on what you have already established in you linear algebra class or what facts are given in your textbook.
We are given a basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of a vector space $V$ over $\Bbb R$ and linear transformations $S,T: V \to V$. Let $[S]_B$ denote the matrix representation of $S$ relative to $B$, and for a vector $v \in V$ let $[v]_B$ denotes the coordinate vector of $v$ relative to $B$.

Note/show that for $n \times n$ matrix $M_1,M_2,$ $M_1 = M_2$ holds if and only if for every vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $M_1x = M_2x$.
Note/show that every $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is equal to $[v]_B$ for some $v \in V$.

In other words, in order to show this equivalence, it suffices to show that
$$
[T \circ S]_B[v]_B = [T]_B[S]_B[v]_B, \quad \text{for all } v \in V. \tag{*}
$$

Note/show that we have $[\phi]_B[v]_B = [\phi(v)]_B$ for any linear $\phi:V \to V$ and $v \in V$.

With that, we can show that both sides of Equation ($*$) above are equal by noting that
$$
[T \circ S]_B [v]_B = [(T \circ S)(v)]_B = [T(S(v))]_B\\
[T]_B [S]_B[v]_B = [T]_B [S(v)]_B = [T(S(v))]_B.
$$
The conclusion follows.

Say $S, T : V \to V$ and $B$ is a basis of the finite-dimensional vector space $V$. We can express $[T]_B$ in terms of the coordinate isomorphism $J_B : \mathbb{R}^n \to V$ given by $J_Be_j = b_j$, namely,
$$[T]_B = J_{B}^{-1}TJ_B.$$
Thus
$$[ST]_{B} = J_{B}^{-1}STJ_{B} = J_{B}^{-1}SJ_{B}J_{B}^{-1}TJ_{B}=[S]_B [T]_B.$$

I'll prove a slightly more general result. The argument that follows was covered in my Linear Algebra I class on November 2023.
Proposition. Let $V,W$ and $U$ be arbitrary vector spaces over any field $\mathbb{K}$ and two linear transformations $F:V \to W$, $g:W\to U$. Now, let $B=(\vec{v}_1, \ldots, \vec{v}_m)$, $D=(\vec{w}_1, \ldots, \vec{w}_n)$ and $E=(\vec{u}_1, \ldots, \vec{u}_s)$ be ordered bases of $V,W$ and $U$, respectively. Then, since the composed transformation $g\circ F:V\to U$ is also linear, the following matrix relation holds: $$\left[g\circ F\right]_B^E=\left[g\right]_D^E\left[F\right]_B^D.$$
Proof. Set $\left[F\right]_B^D=(a_{ij})$, $\left[g\right]_D^E=(b_{ij})$ and $\left[g\circ F\right]_B^E=(c_{ij})$. Fix $1 \le j \le m$. Then, by definition, we have that
$$(g\circ F)(\vec{v}_j)=\sum_{\ell=1}^s{c_{\ell j}\vec{u}_{\ell}}.$$
In addition, we observe that
$$(g\circ F)(\vec{v}_j)=g(F(\vec{v}_j))=g\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{a_{ij}\vec{w}_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_{ij}g(\vec{w}_i)},$$
and so,
$$(g\circ F)(\vec{v}_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_{ij}\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^s{b_{\ell i}\vec{u}_{\ell}}\right)}=\sum_{\ell=1}^s{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{b_{\ell i}a_{ij}}\right)\vec{u}_{\ell}}.$$
Thus, $$\sum_{\ell=1}^s{\left(c_{\ell j}-\sum_{i=1}^n{b_{\ell i}a_{ij}}\right)\vec{u}_{\ell}}=\vec{0}_{\mathbb{K}}.$$
Now, since $E$ is a basis, the set of vector $\{\vec{u}_1, \ldots, \vec{u}_s\}$ is linearly independent, from which it follows that for all $1 \le \ell \le s$ and $1 \le j \le m$ we have that $$c_{\ell j}=\sum_{i=1}^n{b_{\ell i}a_{ij}},$$
which by definition means that $$\left[g\circ F\right]_B^E=(c_{ij})=(b_{ij})(a_{ij})=\left[g\right]_D^E\left[F\right]_B^D, \text{q.e.d.}$$
